# iOS drag & drop for UIPageControl

Tags: iphone, ios, drag-and-drop, uipagecontrol

Is there a way to implement for iOS a drag and drop behavior for a custom icon located in the first page of a UIPageControl to the second page (like moving icons from iPhone's home screen to a different page)?

Thanks.

Comment: verify ur question plz \

Comment: Have you tried checking the position of the moving object, and if object.position.x stays over 300 for 1 second, you switch the page ? I'm not sure as I don't use UIPageController much, but that's the first thing I would try in your situation :)

Answer (score 0):

`UIPageControl` is only a controller to display dots to indicate the number of scrollable pages in `UIScrollView`.

You need to use `UIScrollView` and using `UIScrollViewDelegate`.